Cannot start the IDE Android Studio

После установки Android Studio выходит ошибка, как можно решить проблему?

Можно попробовать переименовать "новую папку", так что там не было русских букв

эта ссылка у вас в ошибке https://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors =>основное, что я почерпала => 1. Найдите папку с плагинами (idea.plugins.path) и удалите её содержимое. Попробуйте запустить Android Studio снова. 2. Ошибка указывает на проблему с UTF-8. Убедитесь, что файлы .vmoptions находятся в корректной кодировке (UTF-8) 3. Удалите кеши IDE, которые могут быть повреждены:
Папка кешей: C:\Users<ваш пользователь>.AndroidStudio<версия>\system\caches
